# Is there a good framework or package in python to compare something over a number of parameters?

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, scientific-computing, experimental-design

When working in python for research I often end up with some problem where I want to compare a result over a different number of parameters.

```
params1 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
params2 = [5, 10, 50]
parmas3 = range(8)

for (p1, p2, p3) in itertools.product(params1, params2, params3):
    result = evaluate(p1, p2, p3)
```

Is there some good way to manage a setup like this for many parameters, where I have a good way to

- save the results
- plot and analyse them conveniently
- probably running multiple experiments in parallel
- maybe even some caching and saving of intermediate results (e.g. if you want to continue the run later

I was thinking that this must be a pretty common pattern, but I was not able to find something that even slightly goes into this direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you build models using the sci-kit learning library, then sci-kit has an internal package called [model_selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_selection.html).
specially, [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) good for your case.

- scikit-optimize
- hyperopt
- Spearmint
  are popular libraries for hyperparameter optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am not really after optimization here. As a first step, I am looking for something that executes my code for all the combinations of that hyperparameters and just stores and/or visualizes different metrics. Maybe optimization is the second step, but for now I only want something that runs these "experiments".